# yii2 Set default configuration of ActionColumn in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I want to set a default configuration for all my GridViews.
I did this as following:

app\config\web.php:

```
require __DIR__ . '/container.php';
```

app\config\container.php:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;

\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\GridView', [
    'layout' => "{items}\n{summary}\n{pager}",
    'columns' => [
        [
             'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
             'template' => '{edit}{update}',
             'buttons' => [
                'edit' => function ($url, $model) {
                  return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', [Url::to(['edit', 'id' => $model->id])]);
                },
             ],

        ],
    ],
]);
```

the part where I define the `layout` works fine.

But apparently the part with the `ActionColumn` doesn't work, because the whole array-index `'columns'` gets overwritten by the column-names when I actually use the GridView in a list.

How can I set default settings for ActionColumn for all GridViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the default values for ActionColumn separately:

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\grid\ActionColumn', [
    'template' => '{edit}{update}',
    'buttons' => [
        'edit' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', [Url::to(['edit', 'id' => $model->id])]);
        },
    ],
]);
```